Non-complete space verifying uniform boundedness
Recently, I have seen the so-called uniform boundedness theorem, which says:

Let $(X,∥⋅∥)$
be a Banach space and $(Y,∥⋅∥)$
be a normed linear space. Let $A⊂B(X,Y)$
be a pointwise bounded family of bounded linear transformations from $X$
to $Y$
. Then the family $A$
is uniformly bounded.

I was wondering if there is any 'simple' non-Banach space that verifies this property: that is, that for all choices of $Y$, a pointwise bounded family of bounded linear transformations is uniformly bounded.
I have thought that maybe some kind of sequence space might work, but I have not quite found one that does.
EDIT: I found in a book that the space consisting on the real sequences that take on finitely many distinct values is an example, but it does not include a proof. Is this proven easily?

Can you provide a reference to the book where you saw this?

The vector space of real sequences with finite support is not a counterexample when equipped with any reasonable norm such as an $\ell_{p}$ norm, which is shown here. However, the uniform boundedness theorem still holds if $X$ is a barrelled space. There is some helpful information here and here which show that such examples exist. You will most likely need to look to barrelled spaces to find explicit examples.

You should not ask the same question simultaneously on MSE and MO. I answered it on MO but it is more appropriate for MSE.

@DeanMiller That is not the space I wrote.

@Jochen Thanks for answering but I would like to know if the space I mentioned is indeed barreled.

You did not specify the topology of the space $\varphi$ of scalar sequences with only finitely many non-zero terms. It is barrelled if you take the topology of the countable direct sum of lines but for the usual norms induced by $\ell^p$ it fails to be barrelled.

@Jochen not with the supremum norm? I am not referring to $c_{00}$. I am referring to the sequences that take on only finitely many different values, for example $(1,2,1,3,0,1,2,1,3,0,\ldots)$ would be in the space.

Okay, I did not read carefully enough. This space is indeed barrelled. This can be deduced from the example 4.7.2 (the measure space is just $\mathbb N_0$ with the counting measure) in the book of Bonet and Perez Carreras.. Unfortunately, they don't give a proof but refer to I.3 Corollary 4 in the book Vector Measures of Diesetl and Uhl (which I do not have at hand right now).

@Jochen Okay, thanks. So I guess that, in this particular case, it is way easier to see that it is barrelled than to prove directly that this space has the uniform boundedness property? I mention this because the author of the book I have just mentions this fact without proof.

I found an old article of Saxon Some Normed Barrelled Spaces
which are not Baire (https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01351318.pdf) who mentions your example (1.4, maybe, that is the first appearance). But again, the proof is mainly a refernce to a theorem of Darst...

@TomassmithSmith Apologies for the confusion.
